How to debugger in vite.config.ts use vscode javascript debugger
I create a vue project use vite. I can debugger file in src folder. But i can't debugger file outside src folder, like vite.config.ts.
Below is launch.json.
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:5173",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}

I want add a debugger on plugins: [vue()] in vite.config.ts. It doesn't work. This is my vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

console.log('vite.config.ts')
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()], // add a debugger here
})

This is my tsconfig.json.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

This is my tsconfig.node.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}

How could make debugger vite.config.ts work, thanks


This is vscode tip for breakpoint not work. Couldn't find a corresponding source location, and didn't find any source with the name vite.config.ts.


What do you mean by a debugger on the plugin? What are you trying to do here?

I want to understand how Vue compile SFC. So I try to add a debugger on  plugins: [vue()] in vite.config.ts. So i can  know how @vitejs/plugin-vue compile vue.

Go to GitHub and read the source code or set such a debugger in the npm package itself (node modules). You're probably not gonna be able to do it right in the config. The debugger is not able to go higher than the project you're in.

Yes, i have clone the source code. The vue source code is too complex for me. So i try to know its compile process. The question is breakpoint inside src folder work, but not outside src folder, like vite.config.ts, I guess there is some config of source map

You can maybe reach out to people to get a bit of help but any source code is always a bit hard to get into that's for sure. That's what I'm saying, put the breakpoint higher in the call chain (aka not in the project). Don't think the source map has anything to do here but I am no expert on Vite. I meanwhile do not see how you could achieve your idea in the place you are trying to put the debugger right now.

I need to add js debug terminal, then run npm run dev on js debug terminal, then the breakpoint on vite.config.ts work.




Nvm it actually works. Hm well played!

But i don't know why. Someone tell me run on js debug terminal, then i try. Hope one day i will understand under the hood.

You could also drop VScode and learn a tool from the ground up with something like vim. That way, you'll build your own thing and understand more what's happening, on top of not having breaking changes etc.

While the OP asked about VS Code, the following explains the process for IntelliJ Rider as the intention seems to be "how to debug vite.config.ts" more than a particular IDE.
I'm using Rider 2024.2.7, although, I'm sure it works with previous versions.
Here's the official docs link:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Vite.html#vite_debug_two_rc
USING RUN CONFIGURATIONS

Create an NPM run config with "command" set to "run", and "script" set to "dev" as shown below

When the configuration is run, it will call "npm run dev" as result of the above configuration.

Select the Browser/Live Edit tab as shown below:


Check "After Launch"

Select "Chrome" (at one point this is the only option that worked with JS Debugger)

Check "with JavaScript debugger

Set "URL" to http://localhost:5173 if using the default Vite setup, or whatever your Vite port is configured to.
NOTE: Jetbrains docs say to use port 3300. I've used ports that weren't the debug port and it worked; so, I'm not entirely sure if the port is crucial, but choose your port or 3300 as it doesn't hurt

Set a breakpoint in your vite.config.ts file

Debug the "dev" run configuration as shown below

NOTE: This didn't work the first time for me. It did after a second round of running the dev config in debug mode

Stop debugging by selecting the stop button next to the run configuration dropdown as shown below



USING PACKAGE.JSON
Additionally, the scripts can be run by opening package.json

Open package.json

Select the play button next to the desired script:

This will display the following options:


Select "Run debug"
This will trigger the breakpoints in vite.config.ts (or vite.config.js).


Troubleshooting
If you're breakpoints aren't triggered:

Open the run config corresponding to the script you're trying to trigger in package.json.
Each script should be displayed automatically in the "Run/Debug Configurations" dropdown as shown below.

If a script listed in package.json isn't shown in the run configurations, select the play button so the script runs at least once. You should then see a run config for it. If not, try to restart Rider.

Verify that "dev" settings are as follows:



Verify that "build" settings are as follows:



If the above didn't work, try deleting the run configurations, and re-run the script from package.json.
This one worked for me in Rider after nothing else did, including clearing caches and updating Rider.

If you're still having issues, try to open just your vite project in WebStorm - and not the entire mono repo if the Vite project is embedded.
I've had better success with WebStorm, and haven't even been required to setup the run config to launch an external browser and user the javascript debugger.


